# ACCUMULATIVE DELAY in Sending a NON_STOP serial stream over ip - Real Time issues?

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, real-time

I've written a program in C++/Qt that reads data from the serial port (ttyS0) and writes it over the network (on a specific TCP port).
At the other end of the network, I read the data from the corresponding socket and write it back over the serial port.

I' ve essentially created a transparent serial-to-serial bridge over the ip network.
So far so good.

The problem starts when the input serial data comes in NON-STOP. Sending the non-stop serial stream (@19200bps) over the network (@100Mbps) and back over the remote serial port (@19200bps) creates an ACCUMULATIVE DELAY.

The first serial packets are sent over the REMOTE SERIAL interface with neglible delay (i.e. the total delay from the time I receive the serial data @ local side to the time i write it over the remote serial port is negligible)
But the delay just adds up and after some time, the "SERIAL pkts" received at local side can be seen at the remote serial port with huge delays (in the order of "minutes" and counting up)!!

Some notes:

- I am using 2 linux boxes that are directly connected (so network delay is not an issue)
- no pkt/serial data is lost in the process (the only problem is accumulative delays)
- my OS is not real time, does this have to do with reat time issues!!

I believe the problem stems from small delays that result in the remote serial port becoming IDLE for short amounts of time.
Since data can leave the system @19200 bps, any delay in the process that might cause the remote serial port becoming idle with lead to an accumulative delay.

But I've no idea on how to measure the delays or make the program to work timely.
Any help/hints are highly appreciated

Comment: The data coming in will be being packetised before being sent over the network, the TCP stack may well be waiting for more data due to Nagle's algorithm too before sending. These delays would probably add up and contribute to your problem. Do you have `TCP_NODELAY` set?

Comment: If the computers are relatively modern they will be able to process the packages received from the serial port much faster than what it can be sent. The network is several thousands of times faster than the serial communication and hardly a bottleneck. So the only possibilities left are your programs and how you handle the communication and process the packets. Start by using the compilers profiler to see if you can find any bottlenecks.

Comment: You can also attach a timestamp (using the highest resolution clock available) to the packet as it arrives on the serial port, then get a timestamp once you are actually sending it to the remote system. Compare the timestamps and see how much time it takes to process a single packet. Do the same on the remote side, but the opposite way.

Comment: The serial driver could assemble several characters before giving a packet to the reading program. In my experience, and depending on the serial config, this could lead to delays much greater than the ones generated in the network part. How exactly is the serial port configured?

Comment: Network delays and sending-side delays all have upper bounds -- they won't accumulate as you described. Off the top of my head, I can think of 2 reasons why an accumulative delay might occur: clock drift (NTP should solve this) and the occasional idle period on the remote serial port (as you suggested).

Do you have a 3rd computer you can use to timestamp the remote serial port's packets? If you set something up that timestamps incoming serial data then you can look for delays.

Comment: Is there a way you can add the occasional break to the communication or transmit faster on the remote serial port than the input port? Unless you have a hard realtime system (which is a lot of work to set up), you will always have the occasional idle period on the remote serial port. Adding in time gaps to your protocol would make resynchronization possible.

If that's not possible and you need to operate indefinitely then you need to make the remote serial communications hard realtime to avoid idle periods.

Comment: @crosstalk: thanks for your input; the program is going to run indefinitely and since should be transpert to the user, thus the speeds at the local & remote serial ports are identical.

Comment: I agree with you that my program should be real-time; but considering that the speeds involved are not high (19200bps) and wrIting e.g. 240bytes takes around 100msec I should have more than enough time to get my job done in that period!  Dont you agree? I am modifying my code to add timestamps, etc. ... I will comeback with the feedbacks

Comment: I realize I was incorrect now about NTP solving the clock drift issue. It's the speed of the clock on your serial interface that matters, and NTP doesn't correct that. It's possible the remote port is running slightly slower than the receiving port, which would cause an accumulating delay. Does the buildup happen if you switch the machines around (assuming that is possible)?

Comment: sorry for the long delay; I've found the source of delay; Writing into the serial port takes longer than what it should!!?? Writing 104 Bytes of data @19200 takes about 59 msec while reading the same amount of data takes 54 msec (making a simple math shows that the latter number is correct). Any ideas on how i can speed up the writing process is appreciated!! (My hardware platform is a Beagel Bone Black)